# Kafka's producer value serialization is being ignored in Spring Boot 3.0.0 configuration properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, properties, spring-kafka

Kafka's serialization properties does not work when I try to send an object by Web Controller.
When I submit an object I receive "value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer" but it must be JsonSerializer. Cannot find a solution in Google ;(

```
    acks = -1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-1

...

    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

...

    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

....

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Cannot convert value of class ru.sandwichcloud.SandwichOrder to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: class ru.sandwichcloud.SandwichOrder cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (ru.sandwichcloud.SandwichOrder is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @506c589e; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

My Kafka config properties

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: kafka
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers:
      - localhost:9092
    template:
      default-topic: sandwichcloud.orders.topic
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      properties:
        "[spring.json.add.type.headers]": false
```

I run my application with profile "kafka".

My kafka service:

```
@Profile("kafka")
@Service
public class KafkaOrderMessagingService implements OrderMessagingService {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, SandwichOrder> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public KafkaOrderMessagingService(KafkaTemplate<String, SandwichOrder> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendOrder(SandwichOrder order) {
        kafkaTemplate.send("sandwichcloud.orders.topic", order);
    }
}
```

My controller's post method

```
    @PostMapping
    public String processOrder(@Valid SandwichOrder order,
                               Errors errors,
                               SessionStatus sessionStatus,
                               @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "orderForm";
        }

        order.setUser(user);
        SandwichOrder messagingOrder = orderRepo.save(order);
        orderMessagingService.sendOrder(messagingOrder);
        sessionStatus.setComplete();

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

I tried to set configuration properties by @Configuration but behavior is the same

```
@Profile("kafka")
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, SandwichOrder> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig());
    }


    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, SandwichOrder> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, SandwichOrder> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, SandwichOrder>(producerFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you use springBoot?

Comment: Hi! I use Spring Boot 3.0.0

Comment: I think you have to use org.springframework.messaging.Message to build a payload before sending data by KafkaTemplate

Comment: this tutorial may help you : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGRDMO4rOGcOlnu6QhogZDNFFwiwKh5X9

Comment: I tried MessageBuilder `.withPayload(order)` and the problem is still there :(

Comment: did you add to your project spring-kafka dependency. If so, then in configuration class you need only define a bean that return org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic. No need for KafkaTemplete and other things in config class. If you take a look at the youtube tutorial, you will see how its done

Comment: I tried this as well :) And problem still there

Comment: Did you use kafkaTemplate.send(message); //message created from MessageBuilder and with ..withPayload(order), you have to add .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "sandwichcloud.orders.topic") before build.

Comment: Yes, I did it. Thank you for help. If you have time you can look through my github https://github.com/tsavaph/sandwich-cloud/blob/Chapter9/sandwichcloud-messaging-kafka/src/main/java/ru/sandwichcloud/messaging/KafkaOrderMessagingService.java

Comment: Try without config profiles. Or put all properties in your default config, except maybe bootstrap servers if you want to connect to different clusters. Otherwise, you need to have an `application-kafka.yaml` file for getting a `kafka` profile